# replyToConversation Template of WSO2 ESB Facebook connector giving error when facebook conversationId has $ symbol

Tags: facebook-graph-api, wso2, wso2-esb

replyToConversation Template of WSO2 ESB Facebook connector giving error when facebook conversationId has $ symbol. When I am running the FB graph API call in graph API explorer, it is working fine and my reply is sent to the message thread, howsoever when the same thing I am doing through my custom proxy, it is giving error for connector template -

```
09-26 15:21:56,666] ERROR - TemplateMediator Illegal group reference
ang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
  at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:857)
  at com.damnhandy.uri.template.impl.RFC6570UriTemplate.expand(RFC6570UriTemplate.java:79)
  at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.processUrlTemplate(HTTPEndpoint.java:243)
  at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.executeEpTypeSpecificFunctions(HTTPEndpoint.java:90)
  at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.send(HTTPEndpoint.java:79)
  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.handleNonBlockingCall(CallMediator.java:221)
  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.mediate(CallMediator.java:99)
  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:104)
  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:148)
  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:84)
  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
  at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:210)
  at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
  at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:325)
  at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:371)
  at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My simple proxy looks like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="facebookReplyMessage"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property expression="json-eval($.conversationId)" name="conversationId"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.message)" name="message"/>
         <filter regex="OPTIONS" source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_METHOD')">
            <then>
               <property name="Access-Control-Request-Headers"
                         scope="transport"
                         value="Authorization,content-type"/>
               <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
                         scope="transport"
                         value="Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept"/>
               <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods"
                         scope="transport"
                         value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"/>
               <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" scope="transport" value="*"/>
               <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
               <respond/>
            </then>
         </filter>
         <facebook.init>
            <app-ID>565617690117864</app-ID>
            <app-secret>7185f791565413c58ade8eaed4eef6b</app-secret>
            <apiUrl>https://graph.facebook.com</apiUrl>
            <apiVersion>v2.10</apiVersion>
            <accessToken>AAWP68ZAGBugBAKfY6KtXptb6GbViISbb6hFo2LZAfzatoADpNMZCNGLAw3zlrt909oyFwEobfphKN3IV4WLN8oPuALh9BKF5DVJWUFIZChBmErFLLuSJUn3S7ibr2eXhPlg74IYgRZCOOw5S7Rd6L6cEFeENWRHAvWQEkt5BFwZDZ</accessToken>
         </facebook.init>
         <facebook.replyToConversation>
            <conversationId>{$ctx:conversationId}</conversationId>
            <message>{$ctx:message}</message>
         </facebook.replyToConversation>
         <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

I am kind of sure it is an issue with the FB connector. Would like some insight for resolution from illuminated thinking hats who happened to either face same issue or have experience of developing WSO2 proxy for Facebook message reply.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the Facebook init as follows in your proxy,

```
<facebook.init>
    <apiUrl>{$ctx:apiUrl}</apiUrl>
    <apiVersion>{$ctx:apiVersion}</.   apiVersion>
    <accessToken>{$ctx:accessToken}</accessToken>
</facebook.init>
```

More about the authentication and the operations of Facebook connector can be found in https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/47529303